# SQL Server 18 - merging dates around midnight

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, merge, timestamp

I would like to ask if anyone could help me with this. I have a table with user traffic on websites. The important column is Timestamp which looks like this.

```
|        Timestamp          |
|  2017-06-26 23:52:09.000  |
|  2017-06-26 23:52:22.000  |
|  2017-06-26 23:58:13.000  |
|  2017-06-26 23:52:59.000  |
|  2017-06-27 00:02:35.000  |
```

Timestamps are used to calculate sessions. An hour or so in timestamps means one session. The **problem** is that calculated session is different when the activity on the websites was made after midnight. Thus, the example below makes two sessions, not one.

```
 |  2017-06-26 23:52:59.000  |
 |  2017-06-27 00:02:35.000  |
```

I need to find and merge or somehow connect one Timestamp (after midnight) to others (after midnight). Thank you for any advice. I have been trying for a while but I can´t make any progress.

Comment: Please provide proper sample data, along with the expected results in order to clarify your question. Right now it is hard to tell what you exactly want.

Comment: What do you mean "SQL Server 18"? The latest version of SQL Server is version 15, which is SQL Server 2019. Version 18 won't be out for about 6 years.

Comment: If someone uses the website for 4.5 hours, but they are active at least once every 10 minutes, is that 1 session, or 5?

Comment: This sounds a lot like the gaps and islands problem, which @Gordon Linoff may have addressed below.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to assign sessions based on a gap of an hour in the timestamps.

This is easily done with window functions:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when timestamp < dateadd(hour, 1, prev_timestamp) then 0
                else 1
           end) over (partition by user_id order by timestamp) as session_number
from (select t.*, lag(timestamp) over (partition by user_id order by timestamp) as prev_timestamp
      from t
     ) t;
```

I am speculating on the existence of a user id and that you want to do this *per user*.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use (LEAD(Timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY Timestamp) - Timestamp)?

Comment: Is this a question to the OP, or an answer?